# in VBA i want to get the DATE in the required format?

Tags: vba, excel

I got the date in the format of

-Possible variantions in the format

2018-12-17

2018-1-17

2018-12-1

2018-1-2

the format of cell is GENERAL

RESULT:I want it to convert it into the following format and cells into DATE format

17-12-2018

17-1-2018

1-12-2018

2-1-2018

Thank you for apt response.

```
sub ggf()
Dim retval, BN As String   ' This is the return string.      '
    Dim i As Integer
Dim myStr, BB As String
 AY = Cells(4, 4).Value
 BB = AY
retval = ""
 For i = 1 To Len(BB)
        If Mid(BB, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(BB, i, 1) <= "9" Then
            retval = retval + Mid(BB, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

If Len(retval) = 8 Then
  BX = Left(retval, 4)
  BY = Right(retval, 2)
  BZ = Mid(retval, 5, 2)
   BN = BY.BZ.BX
   MsgBox BN
 Else
End If
Cells(4, 10).Value = BN
End Sub
```

i tried here to covert the date in general format to string and remove the

unnumeric characters and reverse it accordingly and add the seperators later.

but if the length of the character changes the definition will not be valid and

i felt its not the right way to do it.i also failed to add the seperators.

Comment: You basically want to reverse a string in VBA. Here's an example: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1146-excel-reverse-string-word-order.html#a1

Comment: Have you tried anything in VBA, please share it we can help you out..:)

Comment: i added what i tried please go through it, thank you

Comment: i dont have kutools option in my system, can you suggest me a different way, thank you for the help. -Nick.McDermaid

Comment: You really shouldn't go at it with string functions. The original format is the ISO standard date format. Excel (by default) recognises that. If yes, just change the date formatting. If it does not recognise the dates, just add a column next to it with the desired date formatting, and put a simple formula like `=A1*1` there and pull it down. (Assuming A1 has your first ISO date.) Tested, works.

Comment: Or even a `CDate(activecell.value)` will work. Just please don't do horrible text functions on proper standard ISO dates. It hurts my eyes...

Comment: @subha I don't think the code I linked to requires kutools. Did you try it?

Comment: THANKS EVERY One, all your comments has enlightened my knowledge in vba, it is recognising directly thanks to vacip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use format keyword to change it to date format  as you need

```
    Sub ggf()


    Dim retval, BN As String ' This is the return string.
    ' Dim i As Integer
    Dim myStrBB As String
    AY = Cells(4, 4).Value
    BB = AY

    rs = Format(BB, "DD-MM-YYYY")

    Cells(4, 5).Value = rs

    'Debug.Print rs
    MsgBox rs

End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A** like:

[image]

This small macro:

```
Sub DateFixer()
   Dim r As Range, v As String, d As Date
   For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
      v = r.Text
      If v <> "" Then
         ary = Split(v, "-")
         d = DateSerial(ary(0), ary(1), ary(2))
         r.Clear
         r.Value = d
         r.NumberFormat = "d-m-yyyy"
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]